# tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn returns single value in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn is usually used as follows.

```
 encoder_outputs, encoder_state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=fw_cell, cell_bw=bw_cell, 
                                                                  inputs=inputs, sequence_length=sequence_size,
                                                                  dtype=tf.float64)
```

However, when I see the following code, I'm not sure what value is returned in _.

```
output = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(fw_cell, bw_cell, dtype=tf.float32,
                                          inputs = X, sequence_length = seq_len)
_, ((_, output_fw), (_, output_bw)) = output
```

Can you tell me what is returned in _?